# Problemas al abrir un Access

Tags: ms-access

Llevo unos 20 años trabajando en Access, tanto programador como usuario. El pasado viernes apareció un problema nuevo: al cerrar un Access e intentarlo volver a abrir, queda bloqueado; es decir, no lo puedo volver a abrir. Haciendo doble click en el Acceso o en el propio programa, parpadea y no hace nada. Si intento abrirlo desde el propio programa Access me da un mensaje (could no use Archivo.accdb, file already un use) pero tampoco se abre. No trabajo en Red, lo que sí podría explicar el problema si hubiese otro usuario conectado.

La única solución que he encontrado es reiniciar el ordenador, con lo que todos los Access se desbloquean y se pueden usar (aunque sólo una vez). Quedo a la espera de vuestros comentarios.

Comment: Por lo que cuentas es como si el access se quedara en estado zombie despues de cerrarlo y no lo deja volver a abrir por eso.  No se si eso sera bueno para tus datos, que quizas no acaban de guardarse bien en ese caso si reinicias. Una opcion para acceder el access de ese archivo es simplemente matar todos los procesos de access que han quedado zombies y deberia dejarte hacerlo, pero seria como reiniciar, no sabras si tus datos siguen bien, se han guardado, y no han sido corrompidos.

Comment: Supongo que cuando hablas de "matar los processos de Access" te refieres a compactar. Lo he probado y da mensaje de Error. No entiendo qué está pasando pero el jueves todo iba bien y desde el viernes todo mal. El problema no afecta todos los archivos de Access; "a ojo" dría que sólo a los complicados. Con una Access nuevo y vacío, el problema no ocurre.

Comment: No, perdona, lo de matar procesos esa es jerga de linux más bien... matar un proceso en windows seria ir al administrador de tareas y seleccionar todos los access que veas abiertos y pulsar "Finalizar" sobre ellos, y asi evitas reinciar si quieres volver a abrirlo.  En cuanto al problema especifico de tu access ni idea, no conozco lo suficiente access para ayudarte, lo siento.

Comment: Coincido en lo de los procesos fantasma. Por otro lado...¿qué tamaño tiene tu archivo Access? A partir de una cierta cantidad empiezan a dar muchos problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Sé que es un poco tarde (¿más vale tarde que nunca?), pero acabo de ver la duda. Puedes utilizar un script para "matar" los procesos de Access que queden abiertos. Si no te resuelve en este caso, te será de gran utilidad para estos casos. En este vídeo explico cómo hacerlo. https://access-global.net/access-kill-access/
No obstante, te dejo el código aquí para que puedas copiarlo desde aquí:

`strComputer = "."`
`

`strProcessToKill = "MSACCESS.exe"`

`Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _  & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")`

`Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & strProcessToKill & "'")`

`For Each objProcess in colProcess`

`objProcess.Terminate()`

`Next`

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/323491)

Comment: Haciendo caso a @padaleiana, te dejo es script que puedes copiar y pegar en un archivo de texto al que le pones la extensión vbs:

Comment: strComputer = "."
strProcessToKill = "MSACCESS.exe" 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
 & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
 ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & strProcessToKill & "'")

For Each objProcess in colProcess
 objProcess.Terminate()
Next

Comment: Luis, recordá que podés [edit] tu respuesta. Como notarás, los códigos son prácticamente ilegibles en los comentarios.